# What is difference between JavaFX and Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, javafx

I like to know difference between Silverlight and JavaFX. Anybody help me.

Comment: Do we really need yet another JavaFX Silverlight question?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:

- [Some differences among JavaFX, Flex, Silverlight/WPF](http://osum.sun.com/profiles/blogs/2181626:BlogPost:53833)
- [Differences between JavaFX, Silverlight and Flash](http://yedda.com/questions/Differences_JavaFX_Silverlight_7357911757101/)
- [RIAs comparison - part 2 - simple programs](http://my.opera.com/facildelembrar/blog/rias-comparison-part-2-simple-programs)

Answer (score 0):

As much as between Java and .NET. Purpose is more less the same - to replace Adobe Flash and provide better environment than ActionScript. At this stage both technologies are relatively unpopular among consumers (compared to flash).

Answer (score 0):

NON-TECHNICAL

One difference I should add to the discussion is money for adoption. Microsoft is really making a serious bet on RIA apps and Silverlight, very serious and to that extent they are committed financially to the platform beyond development costs but also in willingness to fund initiatives to drive adoption. Things like the Olympics web site, NFL Sunday Night Football and others are showcases for Silverlight and the massive costs of development and operations on those sites are subsidized by Redmond as a means to build the communal acceptance of SL as a viable RIA platform.